# Is there a way to get Bytes downloaded from Firestore?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am loading 3 objects from Firestore. Each object has a url prop for a link in Firebase Storage. My React app reads the collection and then map over it and get the data from each and push to a new array of objects.

I would like to create a loading bar where it gets Bytes downloaded, and total bytes to display. However, I am not sure this is correct. The app gets the link, but it is the browser that renders. Am I approaching this correctly?

Here is my code:

```
import { db } from '../firebase/config';
// db is firebase.firestore();

function Levels() {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [levels, setLevels] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const updatedLevels = [];
    db.collection('levels')
      .get()
      .then((levelsData) => {
        levelsData.forEach((levelData) => {
          updatedLevels.push(levelData.data());
        });
        setLevels(updatedLevels);
        setLoading(false);
      });
  }, []);
  const newLevels = levels.map((levelData) => (
    <LevelCard levelData={levelData} key={levelData.id} />
  ));
  return loading ? <ProgressBar /> : <GameView>{newLevels}</GameView>;
}

export default Levels;
```

I found this [method](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.LoadBundleTaskProgress) `LoadBundleTaskProgress` but not sure how to use it.

Any feedback on code is appreciated as well.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Bundles are a specific set of documents that you define as 'bundled' with your app, and are not designed for general Firestore usage. While it is technically possible to see which documents you would have to access from the cloud vs cache vs snapshot.data(), it would require some extreme measures and bypassing to achieve this as there are no available methods to hook directly into that process.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. How do websites create a loading bar that tells you how much you downloaded so far out of the total then?

Comment: those websites have their size already known to them when they use webpack, the component then compares the current state while it lazy loads the base app

Comment: I do know the total amount of data in my firebase. Do you mind elaborating on how to determine how much I have downloaded so far? Is that a browser API?

Comment: It's really out of the typical scope of firebase itself as none of this is documented and will require you to pull apart the firebase modules and reverse engineering it. you would start by looking at how the snapshot.data() method invokes and returns the data object which comes from a manager - once you hook into that manager, you can compare the firestore cache and look into the current pending downloads and filter based on its path. most of this is summarised from the actual process. firestore downloads are fast enough that there is no benefit from this. I would instead use a count down